# mocking a dialog box inside unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, viewmodel

Please suggest how to mock the dialog box of the following type inside the unit test using moq.

```
void ShowDialog(string windowName, string parentWindowName, 
  Dictionary<string, object> inputFields, 
  Action<Dictionary<string, object>> closeCallBack, 
  Dictionary<string, object> windowProperties = null);
```

I have tried the following thing but its not working :

```
UIServicemock.Setup(u => u.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<string>, It.IsAny<string>, 
  It.IsAny<Dictionary<string,object>>, 
  It.IsAny<Action<Dictionary<string, object>>>, 
  It.IsAny<Dictionary<string,object>>));
```

I think I am missing the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `It.IsAny<T>()` call is a method so needs parentheses after it:

```
UIServicemock.Setup(u => u.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), 
  It.IsAny<Dictionary<string,object>>(), 
  It.IsAny<Action<Dictionary<string, object>>>(), 
  It.IsAny<Dictionary<string,object>>()));
```

Comment: hi thanks a lot but now the question arises how to pass the argument in the callback of this because this method takes a callback type argument ( so that will call the another method) in its second last parameter.

Comment: That's a different question - I would open a new question for that - show the code that actually makes the call that you're mocking as well because it will give more context

Comment: sure please open the new question , Your response will really be helpful   : function call:   uiService.ShowDialog(ViewName.UnlockScriptPassswordDialog, StudioViewName.MainWindow, passwordDictionary, this.OnUnlockScriptSetCallBack, null)

Comment: I meant that you need to open the question. After all, it is you who wants the answer, no?

Comment: I opened another question for this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373691/mocking-a-dialog-box-that-takes-a-callback-type-as-argument