# Mocking a dialog box that takes a callback type as argument

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, viewmodel

I have created the mock setup for the dialog box of type:

```
void ShowDialog(string windowName, 
                string parentWindowName,
                Dictionary<string, object> inputFields,
                Action<Dictionary<string, object>> closeCallBack,
                Dictionary<string, object> windowProperties = null);
```

like:

```
UIServicemock.Setup(u => u.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<string>(),
                    It.IsAny<string>(),
                    It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, object>>(),
                    It.IsAny<Action<Dictionary<string, object>>>(),
                    It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, object>>())).Callback(ViewName.UnlockScriptPassswordDialog,
                                                                      StudioViewName.MainWindow, 
                                                                      passwordDictionary, ,
                                                                      null);
```

Now in the second last parameter I don't know how to pass the argument so that the dialog box can call the another method.

My function call is like this:

```
uiService.ShowDialog(ViewName.UnlockScriptPassswordDialog,
                     StudioViewName.MainWindow,
                     passwordDictionary,
                     this.OnUnlockScriptSetCallBack, null);
```

And this is calling `OnUnlockScriptSetCallBack` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right you want the call to `ShowDialog` to invoke the fourth parameter to the method.  Set it up like this:

```
UIServicemock.Setup(
                    u =>
                    u.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<string>(), 
                                 It.IsAny<string>(), 
                                 It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, object>>(), 
                                 It.IsAny<Action<Dictionary<string, object>>>(), 
                                 It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, object>>()))
             .Callback<string, 
                       string, 
                       Dictionary<string, object>, 
                       Action<Dictionary<string, object>>, 
                       Dictionary<string, object>>(
                                                   (windowName, 
                                                    parentWindowName, 
                                                    inputFields, 
                                                    closeCallBack, 
                                                    windowProperties) =>
                       closeCallBack(windowProperties /* or whatever dictionary should go here*/)
                                                    );
```

This way the parameters passed to `ShowDialog` are sent to the `Action` given to the `Callback` method.  When `ShowDialog` is invoked, the `Action<Dictionary<string, object>>` given as `closeCallBack` will be invoked.

Comment: Yes I will try this out and then will add further comment about this solution working or not.Thanks a lot for the ray of hope.